# Can't import AutoItLibrary in RIDE/Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, autoit, ride

I have Python 3.7.0, Robot Framework 3.2.2 and RIDE 1.7.4.2 installed on Windows 10. I want to use the AutoItLibrary with RobotFramework. I have installed it as follows:

```
pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
```

It installs successfully, however it will not import in RIDE, and the following error message is generated:
"FAILED AutoItLibrrary Importing test library 'AutoItLibrary' failed: com_error: (-2147319779, 'Library not registered.', None, None)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check your python architecture ( is it 32 or 64 bit)**

Just type python and see

[image]

**For 32:**

1. Open cmd in "**Run as administrator**" mode
2. run the command `pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary`
3. Now clone the autoit library source code: [nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary).
4. in the root directory run the below command: `python setup.py install` using cmd in admin mode

**to navigate to root directory use the command `pushd <filepath>' instead of` cd ` if cd doesn't work in cmd opened in admin mode.**

**For 64:**

1. Open cmd in "**Run as administrator**" mode
2. Now clone the autoit library source code: [nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary](https://github.com/nokia/robotframework-autoitlibrary).
3. in the root directory run the below command: `python setup.py install` using cmd in admin mode

**to navigate to root directory use the command `pushd <filepath>' instead of` cd ` if cd doesn't work in cmd opened in admin mode.**

**You can install 64 bit python at:**

Install 64-bit python , the default version is 32 so you ahve to downlad the 64 bit download file from: [Python Releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

and download **Windows x86-64 executable installer**

and install it.

Check if 64 bit is installed:

[image]

**Installed package :**

Open cmd in "Run as administrator mode" and run below command

```
pip install robotframework-autoitlibrary
```

**test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   This is the script for Create Sales Visit Repository
Library     AutoItLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Input Text
    Send        C:\\Users\\ruela\\Documents\\Different images format\\BMP.bmp
```

**Ran as**

```
robot test.robot
```